# API OpenSSL for getting big prime numbers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, api, openssl, primes

Which method of OpenSSL should I call if I want to get a prime number with more than 1000 digits? And If such method exists how can I use OpenSSL in JavaScript program? Here is official OpenSSL source code: https://github.com/openssl/openssl and it seems it is appropriate only for C, C++. I will appreciate any piece of advice.

Comment: A little research would go a long way: [openssl generate prime](https://www.google.com/search?q=openssl+generate+prime). You also have [WebCrypto](https://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/) nowadays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use BN_generate_prime_ex():

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/BN_generate_prime.html

To call from Javascript you would need to use OpenSSL Javascript bindings. Such bindings do exist, e.g.

https://github.com/mgcrea/node-openssl-wrapper

Typically language bindings don't provide bindings for *all* the functions available within OpenSSL. I don't know whether the above or other bindings provide a specific binding for the BN_generate_prime_ex() function.

Comment: Which file from here https://github.com/mgcrea/node-openssl-wrapper do I need in order to check whether BN_generate_prime_ex() function exists or not? I don`t want to incorporate node.js in the project. I need exactly one js file.

Comment: Sorry. I'm not familiar with those specific bindings I merely pointed at them as an example. There may be other js bindings available.